# Apache: LocationMatch or ProxyMatch doesn't work with RegEx

Tags: apache-2.4, django

I want to redirect requests for a exact specific location to proxy server but both solutions doesn't work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName exmaple.com

<LocationMatch "^/test01$">
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
</LocationMatch>

<ProxyMatch "^/test02$">
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
</ProxyMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Test:

```
$ curl -I exmaple.com/test01
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 15:37:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

$ curl -I exmaple.com/test02
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 15:37:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

When I remove the RegEx part then it works but I want Apache to display the 404, not the Django development server:

```
<LocationMatch "/test01">
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
</LocationMatch>

$ curl -I exmaple.com/test01
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 15:42:26 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 12767

$ curl -I exmaple.com/test01/none
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 15:42:33 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 2073
```

**Update: Mon 18 Jun 14:40:59 UTC 2018**

So I've done some further research and according to Apache [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> When used inside a `<Location>` section, the first argument is omitted
>   and the local directory is obtained from the `<Location>`. The same will
>   occur inside a `<LocationMatch>` section; however, ProxyPass does not
>   interpret the regexp as such, so it is necessary to use ProxyPassMatch
>   in this situation instead.

So I tried `ProxyPassMatch` and it works however the RegEx matched is passed to Proxy `http://localhost:8000/test01` and this is not what I want.

I can achieve this easily with Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name exmaple.com;

    location = /test01/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

How I can do something similar with Apache?

**Update: Sun 24 Jun 10:46:12 UTC 2018**

```
<LocationMatch "^/test01$">
  Redirect / http://test.com/
</LocationMatch>

$ curl -I exmaple.com/test01
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 24 Jun 2018 10:47:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://test.com/test01
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: I think you need to balance your slashes as explained in the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) manual: *If the first argument ends with a trailing `/`, the second argument should also end with a trailing `/`, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.*

Comment: `ProxyPass`|`ProxyPassMatch` can not have a path (first argument) when defined in a location.

Comment: Can you post the config for ProxyPassMatch. Are you adding $1 at the end back-end URL in ProxyPassMatch?

Comment: No, I don't. The query matched is appended automatically, please see my latest update: `Update: Sun 24 Jun 10:46:12 UTC 2018`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way with Apache of solving the problem of:

- sending all sub-paths under a root to an upstream
- hiding upstream-issued 4xx and 5xx errors with static pages

is to use a plain Location block with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, along with ProxyErrorOverride and ErrorDocument. Untested example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName exmaple.com
  ProxyErrorOverride On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ErrorDocument 404 "That resource was not found"

  <Location /test01>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

See:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyErrorOverride
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: Thanks, almost ideally, Nginx also process successful requests (`2xx`, `3xx` etc.) with Apache I can see server headers from a proxy server.

Comment: Want to say more- are you trying to hide upstream headers? Feel free to edit the question. Nginx has several areas where it is more flexible, but Apache should be able to satisfy common cases.

Comment: I guess hiding `server` header can be done only with some rewrite rules?

Comment: Rewrite is more for URL transformation, rather than header transformation, but should be able to modify Server header in various ways with other directives. See the top voted non-accepted answer in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/change-apache-httpd-server-http-header#193677. Try adding directives "Header unset Server" "ServerSignature Off" "ServerTokens Prod". You might need to enable additional modules.